# Nvidia GTX 930M no "Sync to v blank" button

Tags: drivers, nvidia, battery, proprietary, tearing

In "Nvidia X Server Settings" with a **GTX 770**, under "OpenGL Settings" There are two check-boxes called "Sync to VBlank" and "Allow Flipping" which fix screen tearing.

However with a **GTX 930M** these two check-boxes are not there and the screen shows terrible tearing vertically.

How do I fix this tearing with the 930M? (consuming as little battery charge as possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tearing went away when I updated the Nvidia drivers from the ppa.

---

first do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

then

```
sudo apt update
```

Then go to "Additional drivers" (search the dash) and you'll find options to install more up-to-date drivers.

I still can't find the button but I don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Lenovo ThinkPad E540 with Nvidia Optimus - GT740M

I managed to get nVidia drivers working through this article:

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html

I had to pay attention to *every* step, especially the IBus one, that i at first didn't notice (therefore skipped), but doing the IBus step and rebooting solved the issue.

Now i can run programs through nVidia GPU with the help of `optirun` command (only).

[Archived contents of the link in case of the page updating/going down.](https://web.archive.org/web/20161102212225/http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html)